# how to retrieve particular xml element in mule

Tags: mule

```
<splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/productdata/productsList" doc:name="Splitter"/> 
<transformer ref="domToXml" doc:name="Transformer Reference"/> 
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" productsList...#[message.payload]" />
```

i have input xml data as below . I want to display all productname.above code doesn't. any help appreciated.

```
<productdata>
     <productsList>
             <product>
                 <productid>100</productid>
                 <productname>handbag</productname>
                 <desc>accessioes</desc>             
            </product>
            <product>
                   <productid>101</productid>
                 <productname>watch</productname>
                 <desc>accessioes</desc>

            </product>     
         </productsList>
         </productdata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `xpath3` MEL function: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference#MuleExpressionLanguageReference-XpathandRegex

Or `xpath` if using Mule version < 3.6: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/35X/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath3('//productsList/product', message.payload, 'NODESET')]" />

<logger level="ERROR" message=" #[xpath3('productname', payload, 'STRING')]" />
```

Comment: If you want to use xpath to do that you can use the count function:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256103%28v=vs.110%29.aspx So before the splitter, something like: #[xpath3('count(//productsList/product)', message.payload, 'NUMBER')]